# Расшифровать инфу из байтов

Tags: шифрование, байткод

У меня есть 100 байт.
Вот они:

```
65 5A 44 5B 58 44 43 8A 4B 5A 4A 5B 41 4F 58 8A 42 4D 8A 40 4A 46 47 55 84
8A 68 8A 47 4F 45 5A 42 58 55 4D 4A 58 4F 41 56 47 51 5F 8A 40 8A 46 44 4E
4F 8A 45 44 5B 4F 41 4F 47 42 55 5F 8A 46 44 4C 4F 58 8A 5B 41 59 4C 42 58 
56 8A 48 8A 40 4A 5D 4F 5B 58 48 4F 8A 59 40 5A 4A 52 4F 47 42 55 84 A7 A0
```

Теперь они и у вас есть.
В них написан какой-то осмысленный текст. Предположительно русский (выдернуто из игры). Байты как я понял перевернуты. Что это за кодировка такая, что там написано и, чёрт возьми, кто тот герой, что сможет объяснить как их правильно конвертнуть в этом случае?

Comment: Откуда такая уверенность, что тут просто что то написано, а не зашифровано каким нибудь хитрым шифром. уж больно разброс значений ни на какую кодировку не похож. половина в латинской части  ASCII половина в русской. Хотя конечно соглашусь, байты не случайные, совсем мелких значений вообще нет

Comment: В общем моя уверенность вот на каких слонах держится:
1) перед этими байтами явно было указано число 100, такая закономерность повторяется дальше через эти 100 байт, и так на протяжении всего файла. Так обычно помечают строки.
2) сам файл называется description.sdb, что как бы намекает :)
3) есть некая закономерность, например при нормальном порядке байт первый символ - мелкий, дальше все заглавные, при обратном порядке наоборот, что намекает что это строка, начинающаяся с заглавной буквы и байты в обратном порядке.

Comment: Странная уверенность. любые данные можно хранить, предваряя их длиной. в подавляющем большинстве сетевых протоколов идет длина а за ней какие либо данные и текстом они при этом не являются ни разу

Comment: я не спорю, что такие вещи там часты, но архив который я разбираю сейчас целиком направлен на локализацию. Я не буду спорить.
Если вы можете углядеть в этих байтах какие-то другие данные - озвучьте эти варианты.

Comment: Знаешь, тут может быть русский текст, всего 31 уникальный байт, в русском как известно 33 буквы... С другой стороны, самый распространенный 8A - если это пробел, то у нас 13 слов с средней длиной 7 букв, как то многовато

Comment: Кстааати. Огромное спасибо. Вы прямо шерлок, насчет пробелов, пляшущие человечки. Я не догадывался так строки распознавать :О

Comment: Самое длинное "слово" 15 букв. Есть 3 разных слова состоящих из 1 буквы, что то я сомневаюсь, что в предложении одновременно встречаются частицы `и` `с` `в` или `а`. Странно оно выглядит в общем

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Браслет из камня. В непритязательных к моде поселениях может служить в качестве украшения.**

Вы были абсолютно правы, текст, явно из игры :)

Шифр элементарный. С каждый байтом строки в кодировке windows (1251) произведен `XOR` с `0xAA`.

Догадаться было не сложно, по частоте символов мы определили, что чаще всего встречается 8A, предположили, что это пробел. Далее я обратил внимание, что это практически единственный байт, который больше 0x80, остальные байты гораздо меньше. А как известно, у пробела самый маленький код 0x20, латинские символы начинаются с 0x41, а русские так вообще во второй половине таблицы, после 0x80. Получается все крупные числа превратились в мелкие, а маленькое число наоборот в большое - это явный признак операции XOR, тем более она обычно и используется в криптографии т.к. легко обратима, повторением операции. `0x8A xor 0x20 = 0xAA` - вот наш ключ. Сделал маленькую прогу, которая считала ваши шестнадцеричиные коды символов, сделала из них числа и провела `xor 0xAA`. Текст перед нами.

На `perl` моя программа выглядела так:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$a=<>; // Читаем строку из входного файла
@b=split(/ /,$a); // Делаем массив hex кодов, они через проблел
foreach $a (@b) // бежим по массиву
 {
  $n=hex($a) ^ 0xAA;  // Делаем нормальное число из шестнадцетиричного и XOR 0xAA
  print(chr($n)); // Печатаем символ с этим кодом
 }
```

Comment: блин, офигительно :О вы мне очень помогли, в том числе лучше разобраться с тем как можно дешифровать байты. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Вы сделали половину работы, кстати. Вы правильно написали про большие буквы, например. К сожалению, с опытом замыливается глаз, мне в голову придти не может, что кто то в наше время зашифровал, что то таким элементарным способом :) И по этому я сразу не верил, что стоит пытаться расшифровать